# How can i edit a content types taxonomy terms trough the front end

Tags: 8, hooks

I have put the taxonomy terms on the top of the page and i want to add a little cross on each tag to delete that tag (by the users) and also a 'add' button that lets people quickly add a tag to that page.

Does anybody know in which direction i should look? I'm willing to program is but i don't know which hooks i should use or where to put them. I've found pieces of code i could use but nobody ever mentions where to put it.

Comment: A DIY solution: You could create a custom block providing a form with the taxonomy term field, fetching the content (node) from the current route's context and saving the new terms in an according submit callback. Last but not least, place the block on your content pages. Google will help you to get going.

Comment: You may also want to look at the quick edit module (in core).

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the flag module (not ready for D8 yet)

https://www.drupal.org/project/flag

https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/search/flag?project_issue_followers=&status%5B%5D=Open&issue_tags_op=%3D&issue_tags=beta+blocker